# How to include inline tooltip for CCheckListBox?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, checklistbox

I have a standard [`CCheckListBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cchecklistbox-class?view=msvc-170) on my dialog:

[image]

How can I get it to display an inline tooltip whenever the theme is cropped? For example:

[image]

So whenever the mouse hovers over a theme that does not fit it will show a tooltip of the complete theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `CCheckListBox` is a simple list box, you can use all tooltip solutions for it.

This might help

- [`CPopupText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2000/september/c-q-a-cpopuptext-for-home-grown-tooltips-controlling-application-instantiation)
- [ListBox With ToolTip Support](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/cexlistboc.aspx)
- [List Box With ToolTips](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ttlistboxdemo.aspx)
- [`CListCtrl` and Displaying a Tooltip](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/CListCtrl_ToolTip.aspx)

I prefer using a list view in report modes, with checkboxes. The list view supports tooltips by itself. [Sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13586/Using-Check-Box-in-List-Control)

There is also a very old article in the Microsoft System Journal 03/97 "Tiptoe through the tooltips" but I can't find an archive of it.

Comment: Turns out that I am already using a `CTTCombobox` class (see: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10559/Neat-Tooltip-for-ComboBox). I hope that I can adapt some of that for my checked list box. I have everything function with this list box so I don't want to re-code it as a `CListCtrl`, but thanks for the suggestion.